# Organization Browser in SharePoint 2010 empty unless used on My Site

Tags: web-part, user-profile, organization-browser, my-site

I have been trying to get the organization browser web part to work on a publishing site and I can't get the web part to display any users. When I look at the organization browser web part on the my site pages, it works as expected. I *think* the same profile service is being used by the publishing site (I only have one profile service) but I am not sure how to verify this.

Does this web part only work on My Site pages?

Comment: When it was in Beta I was able to get it working on a team site.  I just tried to add it to a publishing site and a team site and it shows up blank.  If I click the HTML view it renders my org correctly which means it should be configured and seeing my user info.  I'll see if I can get it to work on my end.

Comment: I'm having the same trouble, have ya'll gotten any further?

Comment: No progress on my end, we gave up on it. It seems to only work on the MySite pages.

Comment: I opened a post with MS and they confirmed it to be an issue with no workaround.

Comment: A guy in the newsgroups says "Organization webpart use a data souce that you can find when you open mysite page in sharepoint designer.

If you place that data source on the page where you want to use Organization webpart it will work"

I've searched for this "data source but haven't been able to find it.  Does this spur any new ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This fixed my issue. I added the crossdomain.xml and clientaccesspolicy.xml file to my mysite webapplciation rootfolder.

Br,
Robin

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar issue, let me walk you through
1. When My Site host is on another web application you need to add the clientaccesspolicy.xml file in the root of your web application, in Inetpub. If MySites host in on the same web app it works without (but is not done)
2. I've copied from the OrganizationView.aspx page (which is provisioned in the root of your MySites host), 2 important tags:

```
a. the **SPWC:PeopleBrowser** tag, which is the actual Organization browser Silverlight web part
b. the `<SPSWC:ProfilePropertyLoader id="m_objLoader" LoadFullProfileOfCurrentUser="true" runat="server" />` which enables actual load of the property values
```

3. Once this is you could by example use, the same way as Person.aspx does, use the QueryString to pass account name to put in center, otherwise by default it takes currently loggedin user.

Hope it helps,
c:\Marius

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are crawling the sps3://: in your content source.

Central Admin - Manage Service applications - search service application - content sources - choose your content source and make sure that the sps3 address is in the start addresses...If it isnt put it in, if it is then make sure it is correct (should be the same as the Http address of your main site but with sps3:// at the start)

Then do a crawl, and it should pull through.

That worked for me

Answer (score 0):

It's crossdomian situation when javascript is asking another webapplication.In IE it isn't allowed  but you can turn it off in IE configuration for zone's. And for silverlight you must add two file crossdomain.xml and policy file. I don't remember what is the name's of this files.